# Как изменить цвет елемента при выполнений условия?

Tags: html, css, json, typescript, angular

Есть файл JSON с данными, которые выводятся в HTML разметку. Данные между собой связаны полем `joinedWith` и `id`. Первым выводится объект с `id` после чего остальные у которого `joinedWith` совпадает с `id` первого. Так же ести поле `status` у которого два значения, *"open"* и *"closed"*. У объектов должна проводиться проверка на значение статуса, и если он *open* то цвет елемента должен быть желтым, если *closed* - оранжевый, и если среди объектов оба статуса, то другой цвет будет.

```
[
  {
    "id": 2861,
    "areaId": 1791,
    "joinedWith": null,
    "sku": "3",
    "defaultSku": "3",
    "status": "open",
    "countActive": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2967,
    "areaId": 1791,
    "joinedWith": 2861,
    "sku": "1",
    "defaultSku": "1",
    "status": "closed",
    "countActive": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2969,
    "areaId": 1791,
    "joinedWith": 2861,
    "sku": "4",
    "defaultSku": "4",
    "status": "open",
    "countActive": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2977,
    "areaId": 1791,
    "joinedWith": 2861,
    "sku": "12",
    "defaultSku": "12",
    "status": "open",
    "countActive": 0
  }
]
```

*app.component.html*

```
<!--Container Zona 1-->
<div class="main-container">
  <h3>Zona 1</h3>
  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of itemList">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2861">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.joinedWith == 2861">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="card-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of  itemList">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2971 ">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.joinedWith == 2971">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="card-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of  itemList">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2973 ">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.joinedWith == 2973">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="card-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of itemList.reverse()">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2974 ">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.joinedWith == 2974">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="card-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of itemList">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2970 ">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of itemList">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2979 ">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let items of itemList">
    <div class="card card-1" *ngIf="items.areaId == 1791 && items.id == 2980 ">
      <h4>{{items.sku}}</h4>
      <h5>{{items.defaultSku}}</h5>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Container Zona 1-->
```

Я попытался сделать проверку, но у меня нечего не получилось:

*app.component.ts*

```
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
// @ts-ignore
import item from '../files/things.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'json-file-read-angular';
  public itemList: { id: number, areaId: number, joinedWith: number, sku: string, defaultSku: string, status: string, countActive: number }[] = item;

  checkStatute()
  {
    if(item.status === "open")
    {
      const element = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName('rectangle')[0];
      element.style.background = '#f4e800';
    }
    else if(item.status === "closed")
    {
      const element = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName('rectangle')[0];
      element.style.background = '#f64b25';
    }
    else if(item.status === "closed" && item.status === "open")
    {
      const element = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName('rectangle')[0];
      element.style.background = '#ff9900';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: а зачем получать их из дерева? Angular же не для этого

Comment: как может в поле объекта находиться два значения и open и closed? В поле объекта может находиться только одно значение

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Простите если не точно выразился. Да в поле не может быть два значения одновреммено, я это знаю. Я имел в виду что проверяется вся цепочка связанных объектов посредством поля joinedWith. У этих объектов проверяется статус open или closed, но если в этой цепочке объектов находится не только объекты с статусом open все или с closed, а и те и другие то цвет елемента будет другим. В пример я уже показал часть файла JSON, так вот, первым елементом в цепочке будет с id = 2861, а за ним идут объекты с полем joinedWith = 2861 и у них должен проверяться статус.